# Grafana-web visual read-only/kiosk mode for integration in enterprise app

Tags: grafana

Have a requirement in a project to fully integrate grafana-web in an enterprise app.

Some of the points are:

- Don't show the grafana menu (dashboards are read via API and integrated in the app menu)
- Hide playground buttons for users (even if grafana offers a readonly mode, that only prevents saving not playing around with settings/data)
- For some users allow the edit mode (add rows, dashboard settings, dashboard save ...)
- Disable sharing for all users
- All these are visual quirks in frontend, security level low (evil user can still bypass the hidden buttons and that's OK)
- Create/Delete dashboards is done via API triggered by buttons in enteprise app

As Grafana has nothing like this, I was thinking to load it into an iframe and XSS into it to hide buttons (both UI's will be loaded from the same domain).

Answer (score 4):

I fully understand and accept Torkel and the Grafana team decision not to have a readonly mode in frontend only as an "evil" user can easily query the backend around it, so from a security point of view they are right.

But as you see some edge cases/projects require this even if only as a visual quirk.

**WARNING: Just to be sure you got it, this is a visual styling of grafana-web and does not offer any security, an "evil" user can still have access to everything.**

So here's how I implemented it:

- All users have edit priviledges in Grafana (the buttons are hidden frontend only)
- Load the grafana-web into an iframe
- The iframe either has a mask over (one can also move the iframe our of view or make if fully transparent)
- On iframe DOMContentLoaded handler, we register a MutationObserver on the iframe Document to catch and hide buttons as they are added to DOM, using the amazing [Mutation Summary](https://github.com/rafaelw/mutation-summary) library by Rafael Weinstein.
- Hide the buttons at this stage is they are already rendered, in case the Observer is registred to late (it's a race condition against Angular rendering)
- Remove the mask (move iframe into visible area, make opac ...)

Here's the customizer code triggered by DOMContentLoaded:

```
// Don't forget to load the mutation-summary.js lib

function iframeLoad (iframe) {
    // Disable this if you want users to have access to playground buttons like:
    // add Rows, edit Panels, dashboard settings ...
    readOnlyMode = true;

    // This is the iframe "window"
    var iframe_window = iframe.contentWindow;

    // This is the iframe "document" under which the MutationObserver will look for DOM changes
    var iframe_document = iframe.contentDocument;

    var queries = [{
        // This is the main menu of grafana
        element: '.navbar-brand-btn' 
    },{ 
        // This is the dashboard selection right of the main menu
        element: '.navbar-page-btn' 
    },{ 
        // This is the share button appearing inside the .dashnav-action-icons, we don't want to allow
        // this to anybody, as it's exposes the real url, thus bypassing this code
        element: 'li[ng-show="::dashboardMeta.canShare"]' 
    },{ 
        // This is the dashboard delete button, under dashboard setting button
        element: 'a[ng-click="deleteDashboard();"]' 
    }];


    if ( readOnlyMode ) {
        queries.push({ 
            // This is the three vertical dots button to open the row menu/edit
            element: '.dash-row-menu-grip' 
        });
        queries.push({
            // This is the bottom "+ ADD ROW" button
            element: '.add-row-panel-hint'
        });
        queries.push({
            // This is the share button right of the dashboard menu
            element: '.dashnav-action-icons' 
        });
        queries.push({
            // This is the "Panel" menu triggered by clicking the Panel name
            element: '.panel-menu' 
        });
    }


    var observer;
    observer = new MutationSummary({
        callback: function (changes) {
            changes.forEach(function (change) {
                change.added.forEach(function (el) {
                    iframe_window.angular.element(el).addClass('ng-hide');
                });
            });

            // Normally we disconnect here to free resources, but on new dashboards
            // the buttons will be re-rendered by Angular, so we keep this to block that behaviour
            //observer.disconnect();
        },
        queries: queries,
        rootNode: iframe_document
    });


    // Hide the elements if they are already generated before we registred the Observer
    // is a race condition afterall "Angular rendering" vs "registering the Observer"
    queries.forEach( function (el) {
        if ( iframe_window && iframe_window.angular ) {
            iframe_window.angular.element(el.element).addClass('ng-hide');
        }
    });

    // Remove the mask or move the iframe into view if needed
    // [YOUR CODE HERE]


}
```

This method was tested against grafana version 4.0.0-1476697633pre1 (and the one currently running in play.grafana.org)